# api validate with reference token or JWT

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to get an api to validate a token (both jwt and reference) from Identity server 4. The first part of the token looks like this:

```
{
 alg: "RS256",
 kid: "09E9884444C4E3221983C13333333333333334A",
 typ: "JWT",
 x5t: "CemILYTE3432GGGGGGGGGGGG"
}.
{
 nbf: 1522084412,
 exp: 1522088012,
 iss: "https://authserv:8097",
 aud: [
  "https://authserv:8097/resources",
  "customAPI"
 ],
 client_id: "program",
 sub: "user1",
 auth_time: 1522084412,
 idp: "local",
 scope: [
  "openid",
  "scope1"
 ],
 amr: [
  "pwd"
 ]
}.
```

The setup in startup.cs looks like this:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://authserv:8097";
                options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Both;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           //     options.ApiName = "CustomAPI";
           //     options.ApiSecret = "secret";

            });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = ScopePolicy.Create("scope1");
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
```

In this form the Jason token works. If I uncomment the apiName and apiSecret the JWT no longer works and gives a "The audience is invalid" error. With the apiName and apisecret uncomment the reference token validates correctly. Am I missing something in the configuration to have the JWT valid with the apiName and apiSecret uncommented out?

I am trying to get an environment setup where I can have identity server use JWT or reference token depending on how parameters are set and the api will work with either.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens if you comment out only `options.ApiSecret = "secret";` ? And also - what Grant Type are you using? Is it client credentials?

Comment: I get the same error with JWT if I only comment out api secret. The grant type is implicit.  thanks

Comment: Did you try mi answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a `typo` mistake.

In your JWT I see that the audience (the `aud` claim) is `customAPI` (small letter 'c') while in the configuration of your client, the API name is `CustomAPI` (capital 'C'). Make them to be the same.

Comment: I spent 2 days with an incomprehensible authentication error. You remade my day, my audience was container and Container